# Can't force www with http/https in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm having big troubles to configure my virtualhost with aws elasticbeanstalk and symfony 3.4.

Here's the problem, I want to force 'www' with condition.

For example if the domain is ocean you'll redirect to https://www.ocean.com.

But if the request url is subdomain.ocean.com in that case you must not rewrite with www.

So far, almost everything work.

ocean.com become https://www.ocean.com

subdomain.ocean.com become https://subdomain.ocean.com

But if you try something like http://ocean.com or https://ocean.com. It won't work.

I've tried everything and nothing worked, any ideas ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: Can you please post all the code (minimal working example, however) that we know what you have got already? It's a lot easier to answer then :)

Comment: You contradict yourself in your question. Now what happens if you request `http://ocean.com`, does or does it not "work", whatever "work" actually means here?

Comment: Apart from that... you claim that you "tried everything", yet you do not post a single effort you made...

Comment: You guys are right sorry. So a permant redirect is added in my dns records, to redirect the base domain to www.mydomain.fr. It's working just fine. And I've added this in my apache conf `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.fr/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: There is no such thing as a redirection in the DNS system, you confuse something here. DNS resolves names to adresses, not more.